# How to get the warning - 'unused function' in Eclipse Python (PyDev)?

Tags: python, pydev, pycodestyle

I want to get warnings for unused functions in PyDev, the Python IDE for Eclipse.

I found no option for that in *Code Analysis*. How can I do this?

Comment: Tried this - http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_code_analysis.html ?

Comment: I can't find any manual adv code analysis on that page, can you confirm it for me?

Answer (score 0):

PyDev by default does not have such functionality... Finding unused functions may be extremely difficult due to the Python dynamic nature -- also, it would require whole program analysis (the PyDev code analysis is meant to be fast and with as few false positives as possible without doing whole program analysis, so, this check doesn't really suit the targets on PyDev).

Now, there is a project that seems to implement it: https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture so, it may be an option... or maybe PyLint (PyLint itself is integrated in PyDev -- http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html -- but I think they may not have that functionality either).

Another option could be running with code coverage (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_coverage.html) -- everything not hit could potentially be unused (but that would require a suitable test suite of integration tests which actually test your whole app -- unit tests may end up calling code not used in the real app, which may skew the results -- although you really need a reliable suite of integration tests checking your whole app for this to work).